# Meteor users log in, username using different email address from user's email address

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

By default Meteor's validate user log in is either username and password or email address and password. Does anyone have any idea this case that is unable to log in:

> username is info@abc.com, email address is derr@abc.com
>
> // Unable to log in
>
> username: info@abc.com, password: abc12345
>
> // Able to log in
>
> username: derr@abc.com, password: abc12345

Answer (score 1):

Reference: http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loginWithPassword

> **Meteor.loginWithPassword(user, password, [callback])**
>
> ARGUMENTS
>
> user Object or String
>   Either a string interpreted as a username or an email; or an object with a single >key: email, username or id. Username or email match in a case insensitive manner.

If the first parameter `user` is passed a string, it can be a username or an email. So these two will log the user in.

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword('info@abc.com', 'abc12345')

Meteor.loginWithPassword('derr@abc.com', 'abc12345')
```

If you pass an object as the first parameter, the key must be specified explicitly according to the value passed in. The two below will work, but the keys used are not interchangeable.

```
Meteor.loginWithPassword({
  username: 'info@abc.com'
}, 'abc12345')

Meteor.loginWithPassword({
  email: 'derr@abc.com'
}, 'abc12345')
```

Comment: Hi Season, by default on the blaze template I uses {{> atForm state="signIn"}} which gives username or email address input field and password field only. How to implement with your following examples above?

Comment: I use neither Blaze nor `accounts-ui` package. But I think what happens behind the scene is that the text you typed on the login form gets passed as a string variable by `accounts-ui` to the first parameter `user` of `loginWithPassword`. The thing is that [if the string contains `@`, it is identified as an email address.](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/accounts-password/password_client.js#L24) Therefore either _info@abc.com_ or _derr@abc.com_ are treated as email, and your first login attempt failed.